Spring GraphQL with Spring 5
I'm trying to create a java graphQL client for my app that will consume a graphql endpoint (example : https://countries.trevorblades.com/).
My app uses Spring framework 5 (it's not spring-boot app).
On spring documentation here https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/reference/client.html, You can create a client by providing either RestClient for blocking calls or WebClient for non-blocking calls.
I added spring-webflux dependency so I can use WebClient. My pom.xml looks like this:
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.graphql</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-graphql</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.33</version>
    </dependency>

Then, I have created then a Client builder that uses WebClient:
public class DefaultGraphQlClientBuilder implements GraphQlClientBuilder {

@Override
public HttpGraphQlClient buildClient(String graphQLUrl, Map<String, String> headers) {
    WebClient client = WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl(graphQLUrl)
            .build();HttpGraphQlClient.builder()
    HttpGraphQlClient.Builder<?> graphQlClientBuilder = HttpGraphQlClient.builder(client);
    if (Objects.nonNull(headers)) {
        headers.forEach((key, value) -> {
            graphQlClientBuilder.header(key, value);
        });

    }
    return graphQlClientBuilder.build();
}

When I start my server, I have this exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No suitable default ClientHttpConnector found

I googled that, and it says that I need some netty jars, so I added these dependencies:
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-netty</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-netty</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.33</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-netty-http</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.33</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-netty-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.33</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-resolver-dns</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.94.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-codec-http2</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.94.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphql-java</artifactId>
        <version>22.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.33</version>
    </dependency>

My Server finally starts, but when I try to consume the endpoint like this :
myGraphQlClient.document(query).retrieve(path).toEntity(clazz).block();

myGraphQlClient uses the DefaultGraphQlClientBuilder that uses WebClient
I get this exception:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'reactor.util.context.ContextView reactor.core.publisher.MonoSink.contextView()'
at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$HttpObserver.<init>(HttpClientConnect.java:333)
at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect.lambda$subscribe$0(HttpClientConnect.java:263)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate.subscribe(MonoCreate.java:57)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen.subscribe(FluxRetryWhen.java:77)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoRetryWhen.subscribeOrReturn(MonoRetryWhen.java:46)

So my question is how I can use spring-graphql to create a proper client ? and don't get this exception ?
Thanks

Your reactor-core seem a bit old: I use reactor-core:3.6.4.

Probably your Spring Framework version 5.3.33 is not compatible with your Spring GraphQL version 1.2.4.
When I look into the dependencies of Spring GraphQL in the source repository (spring-graphql/platform/build.gradle I see a dependency to org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:5.3.30 up to version 1.0.6 of Spring GraphQL.
Starting with 1.1.0 it depends on org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:${springFrameworkVersion} where ${springFrameworkVersion} is defined in spring-graphql/build.gradle where it starts with 6.0.0.
For newer versions of Spring GraphQL the version of the Spring Framework dependency is increased, in Spring GraphQl 1.2.4 the relevant Spring Framework is 6.0.14
So I would recommend that you migrate to Spring Framework 6 - ideally a suitable version for a recent version of Spring GraphQL.
Alternatively when you want to stick on the outdated Spring Framework version, you will also have to use an outdated version of Spring GraphQL.
(See e.g. https://endoflife.date/spring-framework for when the support of Spring Framework 5.3.x ends)

Yeah, I can't migrate to Spring Framework 6, so I guess I need to find a compatible Spring GraphQL version, like 1.0.6. Im gonna try that for now? Thank you
